# How to Organise my Room for more space?

Tags: bedroom

I have a small room. How can i organise stuffs to gain more space.I already tried to do things but was unsuccessful

Comment: Hi Edward, Welcome to Lifehacks. We hope you enjoy sharing knowledge and experience. Please give us more information to work with to answer this. How big is your room? What is inside? What must fit that doesn't now? Do you have storage available? What's there that you don't need? The better your information, the better the answer will be for you.

Comment: its a small room with a bed a table a chair and a Cupboard. @Stan

Answer (score 2):

One very useful tip is to find many boxes and containers. If you have shelves, or space under beds, use containers for things, then they can be easily accessed, put away, and out of the way. Only a few types of things per container - everything in a container should be accessible.

The most important thing, is to eliminate anything that does not bring you joy - you don't need all of the things that make your room disorganized.

Answer (score 2):

I use three approaches.

1) Go vertical. Make shelves on your walls that reach to the ceiling. Or stack milk crates or boxes on top of each other from floor to ceiling along one wall. That way, the space toward the top of your room gets used too. (Caution: make sure to attach the higher ones to the wall so the whole stack doesn't fall over!)

[image]

2) Find other odd, unused space around your room. For example, there is probably space under your bed. You can buy or make some under-bed boxes that easily slide in and out so you can access what's in them. Another idea: you may be able to move your bed 6 inches out from the wall, and put a set of 6-inch-deep shelves between your bed and the wall. You may be able to do the same with your desk.

3) This one is odd, and is only useful if you have a physical desk or workbench that you use for various projects. The idea is to make multiple portable desktops. That way, you can use a a different desktop for each project you're working on. To do this, get a few large sheets of 1/4" plywood or 1/4" pressboard, fairly smooth on both sides, and cut multiple rectangles that are the size of your existing desktop. Build a set of shelves that you can slide these "additional desktops" into for storage. Those shelves should offer at least 6-8" clearance for each shelf. Put all but one of the "additional desktops" into the shelves. Clear off your desk, put the final "additional desktop" on top of it, and put everything back on the "additional desktop". That'll be the desktop for your current project. When you want to switch projects, pick up that "additional desktop" (along with everything on it), put it on an empty shelf, slide out a new "additional desktop", and place that new "additional desktop" on your desk. Voilà - a clean desk! I'd recommend adding a door or curtain on the front of the shelves you built, so your "additional desktops" don't get dusty while you're not using them.

Comment: +1 for **Caution**: Floor standing shelving units that reach above eye-level will be safer if anchored to a wall for stability. Some areas are prone to earth tremors or strong vibrations from nearby construction sites.